# Donot display the right border of active class

Tags: html, css

Following is my jsfiddle in which i am trying to set the `border-right: none;` of the active `<li>` but its not happening kindly let me know how can i modify the fiddle so the border-right of the active `<li class="active">` doesnot appear. Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/HgCCf/1/

```
.drop-shadow {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    border-right: 2px solid #CECECE;
}

.active
{
    background-color: yellow;
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/HgCCf/2/

The problem is that you applied the border in ul tag and class .active was associated with li tag

```
.drop-shadow li{
   border-right: 2px solid #CECECE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border which you are seeing is that of `UL` not `LI`. You should add border to `li` elements instead of ul.

So

```
.drop-shadow {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
   /* border-right: 2px solid #CECECE;*/  comment this
}
/*and add this*/
.drop-shadow li
{
    border-right: 2px solid #CECECE;
}

li.active
{
    background-color: yellow;
    border-right: none;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgCCf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a general border-right on your main ul.drop-shadow.Look again,i've modified your fiddle,now it works